# Gmail SMTP return 250 OK, but Codeigniter encounter Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-email

I am sorry I still developing apps using Codeigniter 3.X. But I need some advice about my problem. When I try sending email using Email Class with attachment inside the email, sometimes CI encounter error although Gmail SMTP return 250 OK. See picture below.

Good news is email successfully sent to recipients. But I can't ensure that the error is real error. Is there any settings I can change to make sure no error encountered?

[image]

Comment: Hmmm I just solve my own problem.. But anyway, for everyone encounter this issue, please try to increase smtp_timeout in email setting. Good Luck!

Comment: Please post that as an answer, and select it as the correct one

Comment: OK @KetZoomer, I'll do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved my own problem. For everyone encounter this issue, please try to increase smtp_timeout, or something similar with this setting, in email setting.
Good Luck!